# Rijndael encrypted text causes length of data to decrypt is invalid error - C#

Tags: c#, exception, encryption, cryptography

I have searched online but have not been able to find any solutions to my problem.

I am using previously written methods to encrypt and ecrypt text using the Rijndael class.

I use these functions to encrypt and decrypt usernames and emails for a web application I have been working on.

The encryption/decryption works perfectly, but every once in a while I get this error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.
```

Currently, I am getting this error with a specific email address and I can't reproduce the error even if I replace some of the letters in the email.

Here are the encryption/decrytpion functions. The IV and Key are defined as read only strings.

```
    static public string Encrypting(string Source)
{
    byte[] bytIn = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Source);
    // create a MemoryStream so that the process can be done without I/O files
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    byte[] IVBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
    byte[] KEYBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(KEY);

    Rijndael rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
    rijndael.IV = IVBytes;
    rijndael.Key = KEYBytes;

    // create Crypto Stream that transforms a stream using the encryption
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    // write out encrypted content into MemoryStream
    cs.Write(bytIn, 0, bytIn.Length);
    cs.FlushFinalBlock();

    // get the output and trim the '\0' bytes
    byte[] bytOut = ms.GetBuffer();
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < bytOut.Length; i++)
        if (bytOut[i] == 0)
            break;

    // convert into Base64 so that the result can be used in xml
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytOut, 0, i);
}

static public string Decrypting(string Source)
{
    // convert from Base64 to binary
    byte[] bytIn = System.Convert.FromBase64String(Source);
    // create a MemoryStream with the input
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytIn, 0, bytIn.Length);

    byte[] IVBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
    byte[] KEYBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(KEY);

    Rijndael rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
    rijndael.IV = IVBytes;
    rijndael.Key = KEYBytes;

    // create Crypto Stream that transforms a stream using the decryption
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rijndael.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    // read out the result from the Crypto Stream
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(cs);
    return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

FYI - I am very new to cryptography and security.

Can these functions be fixed to avoid special cases that cause the error, or should I scrap these and use the `RijndaelManaged` class?

Sites I found that use RijndaelManaged:
[SeeSharp](http://www.seesharpdot.net/?p=141)

[TekEye](http://tekeye.biz/2015/encrypt-decrypt-c-sharp-string)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BNHLU1Tc try this ones and say if same error will occur. The problem as I see related to invalid padding of data to decrypt. Or invalid settings for decrypted data padding, so the method can't calculate the correct size of pure encrypted bytes without padding.

Comment: Have you verified that the values you're trying to decrypt were encrypted with the same text encodings?

Comment: @Kosmos - Thanks, I'll play around with that.

Comment: @CamBruce - Yes I'm sure. All the code is above and to be sure I have a text app that encrypts and decrypts text. The issue is with the algorithm and how certain strings can cause it to throw that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is almost certainly nothing to do with `Rijndael` vs. `RijndaelManaged` (or any other such implementation), but instead because the encrypted data contains a `0x00`, and you are incorrectly assuming that the the ciphertext ends at the first `0x00` byte. Since the ciphertext can legitimately contain *any* byte value you should instead use the stream's `Length` property to determine the length of the ciphertext.

Eliminate the section you've commented: "get the output and trim the '\0' bytes" and replace the `return ...` statement with:

```
return System.Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.Length);
```

It should be noted that there are many other issues with your use of cryptography here, e.g. the use of a key generated directly from the ASCII encoding of a string, and the fact you're using a fixed IV both negatively impact security.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue, although the ms.Length is a long, I had to convert it to int using `System.Convert.ToInt32(ms.Length)`.

Comment: @RXC A straight cast to `int` should be fine (i.e. `(int)ms.Length`), no need for the much longer `System.Convert...`.

Answer (score 0):

The norm for the error is a padding issue. What version of .NET are you using? It is more common to use the AES classes (AES, or Advanced Encryption Standard, which is Rijndael). There are plenty of AES implementations you can find as samples.

If you need some proof AES is Rijndael: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

Comment: I am using .Net 3.5. Thanks for the wiki link. I had hoped that maybe there was a simple fix for this but I may be better off like you said using a different implementation.